# Copy file from local

Tags: java, hadoop

I'm trying to copy a file from local to hdfs in these three ways:

```
    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(context.getConfiguration());
    LocalFileSystem lfs = fs.getLocal(context.getConfiguration());

lfs.copyFromLocalFile(new Path("file:///pathToFile/file.properties"), new Path("/destPath/"));

fs.copyFromLocalFile(new Path("file:///pathToFile/file.properties"), new Path("/destPath/"));

fs.copyFromLocalFile(new Path("file:///pathToFile/file.properties"), new Path("/destPath/"));
```

But none of them are working. 
I always get a FileNotFound exception for /pathToFile/file.properties, but the file exists on that path on Unix and has read and write permissions for the user that runs the Map/Reduce.

Any ideas what I'm missing here?

Job is running with Ozzie
CDH4

Thank you very much for your help.

opalo

Comment: how about the directory permissions in which the file is residing

Comment: It seems to be ok drwxr-xr-x

Comment: Do you need 3 forward slashes?

Comment: I also tried with fs.copyFromLocalFile(new Path("/pathToFile/file.properties"), new Path("/destPath/"));

but it didn't work either. 

The thing is that I can see in many posts that this is the way. But I'm missing something that makes my code fail.

Answer (score 0):

Where is this code running?

If this code is running in a map or reduce method (as it seems because you have a Context instance), then you are executing on one of your slave nodes. Can all of your slave nodes see this path or can only the cluster's login node see the file?

If this code is in fact supposed to be running in a mapper or reducer, and the file is not local to these machines (and you do not want to put the file(s) into hdfs with a "hdfs fs -put" command), one option you have is to deploy the file(s) with your job using the hadoop distributed cache. You can do this programmatically using the [DistributedCache](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/filecache/DistributedCache.html) class's static method addCacheFile, or through the command line if your main class implements the [Tool](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.3.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/util/Tool.html) interface by using the [-files switch](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.3.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/CommandsManual.html#Generic_Options).

**Programmatically (Copied from the documentation linked to above):**

```
JobConf job = new JobConf();
DistributedCache.addCacheFile(new URI("/myapp/lookup.dat#lookup.dat"), ob);
DistributedCache.addCacheArchive(new URI("/myapp/map.zip", job);
DistributedCache.addFileToClassPath(new Path("/myapp/mylib.jar"), job);
DistributedCache.addCacheArchive(new URI("/myapp/mytar.tar", job);
DistributedCache.addCacheArchive(new URI("/myapp/mytgz.tgz", job);
DistributedCache.addCacheArchive(new URI("/myapp/mytargz.tar.gz", job);
```

**From the command line if your main class implements [Tool](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.3.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/util/Tool.html) interface:**

hadoop jar Your.jar Package.Path.To.MainClass -files comma,seperated,list,of,files program_argument_list_here